# Why doesn't Pandas Groupby with single aggregate (Series object) preserve column name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by, series

Pandas Groupby with aggregate function does not preserve column name unless passed a list

This question is not a question on how to solve an issue, but to understand the behavior that I am seeing.

I have a statement like this:
`df2 = df.groupby(by='x)['y'].mean().sortvalues()`
This produces a Pandas Series without the column name preserved.

But if I pass a list instead of a single column, and add a sort by statement, I get a dataframe with the column name preserved.
`df2 = df.groupby(by='x)[['y']].mean().sortvalues(by='y')`

Now I get the same result on my screen but with the column name preserved.

I can use both df.columns and df.index on a dataframe,
but only df.index on a series.

Not only would I like to understand why the Series does not and cannot preserve the column name, I also think it will be useful for others as I searched on this issue and found almost nothing on the topic.

I feel like it would be better for the Pandas Groupby with single aggregate category to require a list as to preserve the column name. The single aggregate on the series object doesn't preserve the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Which pandas version do you use? I tested on an old (1.0.3), not so recent ones (1.4.3, 1.5.3) and a recent version (2.0.1) and this is working well:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'y': [1,2,3,4]})

df2 = df.groupby(by='x')['y'].mean().sort_values()

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
┌── grouper name (=index)
x
a    1.5
b    3.5
Name: y, dtype: float64
      └── Series name
```